# Search in a list of variables SQL

Tags: sql, list, variables

I know this question is really basic but I am very new to SQL, could you tell me what is wrong about this attempt I am making at searching a table based on a variable? The variable @position is supposed to come from a list of numbers...

```
set @position := 171839648, 171844431, 171846532;

select chrom, chromStart, chromEnd, name, score
from wgEncodeRegTfbsClusteredV3
where chrom = "chr5" and @position BETWEEN chromStart and chromEnd
```

When I use `set@position := 171839648;` the code works fine, but not when I add more items, and I haven't been able to figure out how to make the variables be selected from a list.

Sorry for the stupid question and thanks for your help!!

Stefanie

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  This is not really an SQL question, but rather a question about the procedural extensions used with SQL in your particular database (i.e. PL/SQL for oracle, T-SQL for MS SQL Server).  In general the issue is variable type.  You'll likely have to store the values in a type suitable for holding a list, and then either use a loop to execute the query for each value, or dynamically generate the query with a more complex predicate (`(*value1* between chromStart and chromEnd OR *value2* between chromStart and chromEnd OR ...)`)

Comment: I think this would be relatively easy to solve if that list of numbers was in it's own table. As an actual list, it could get a little tricky. What RDBMS is this?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your where cond something like this -

```
where chrom = "chr5" and chromStart in (@position) and chromEnd in (@position)
```